# 'Alignment' Tags being added whenever I move a rectangle in C# WPF

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, canvas

I am currently learning how to create a WPF app in C# Visual Studio 2022 and an issue arose which I couldn't find a fix for online.

I am following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n4s1QJPbLog which uses canvases rather than grids.

Whenever I try and move a rectangle using the mouse or the arrow keys, the tags `VerticalAlignment` and `HorizontalAlignment` will assign themselves automatically. eg moving

```
<Rectangle Tag="coin" Height="10" Width="10" Fill="Gold" Canvas.Left="231" Canvas.Top="144"/>
```

to the left will turn it into

```
<Rectangle Tag="coin" Height="10" Width="10" Fill="Gold" Canvas.Left="229" Canvas.Top="144" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

I assume it's something to do with the settings, but there's a lot of areas to look through and it is quite overwhelming.

I also understand it doesn't really impact the program but it stills annoys me when reviewing my code.

Any fixes would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The canvas should positions elements absolutely. [Automatic Layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/use-automatic-layout-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#automatic-layout-and-coding-standards)

According to my test, I clicked the Rectangle in the Canvas and moved it in the designer, and the Alignment was not added. Could you describe your VisualStudio version?

```<Canvas>
    <Rectangle Tag="coin" Height="10" Width="10" Fill="Gold" Canvas.Left="312" Canvas.Top="177"/>
</Canvas>```

Comment: Hi! I'm using visual studio community 2022 version 17.8.6. I made a mistake in my post sorry, it only happens when I move the arrow keys or copy and paste a rectangle. Here is a video of the issue: https://youtu.be/8fi9OjV-5FY. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi,@CriticalCloud.  Could you share your video here as a screenshot gif? Due to policy reasons, I can't see this video on YouTube.